# Linux configuration of net.ipv4.tcp_rmem

Tags: linux, ipv4

I'm trying to create a script with this command:

```
    sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=65536 87380 16777216
```

However, I get this error:

```
    net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 65536

    error: "65536" must be of the form name=value

    error: "16777216" must be of the form name=value
```

I researched on the internet and the command is valid, yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the value so it's presented as a single "value", as in

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="65536 87380 16777216"
```

Comment: That worked! Didn't think of making it a string.